# Can't read my class from file (Android)

Tags: java, android, serializable, notserializableexception

Iv'e been searching a bit and couldn't find an answer... I've created a class and successfully saved an ArrayList of my class to a file but when I'm trying to read this file I keep on getting:

> E/Reading file(14768): java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an
>   exception; java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   il.co.hyperactive.callmaagansmallgate.Gate

here is my class:

```
public class Gate implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3L;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Gate(String name, double longitude, double latitude,
            String phoneNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public Gate(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPlace(double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + "\nLatitude:" + latitude + "\nLongitude:" + longitude
                + "\nNumber:" + phoneNumber;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try recompiling it once again

Comment: Where did **java.io.WriteAbortedException** come from here, is that the contents of your file?

Comment: You might check this answer for some info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885968/java-io-notserializableexception-unable-to-deserialize-hashmap-in-java

Comment: Jigar, I built it and recompiled it for several times.. 
Elliot, the exception thrown while i tried to read a saved file with an object of this class in the internal storage.
Mike, I already saw this post - didn't help me ... thx to you all anyways

Answer (score 0):

Serializable needs a default constructor, no arguments. So be sure to add:

```
public Gate(){
}
```

This is needed because the compiler only generates a default constructor if there is not one specified. Serialization always calls the default constructor and then fills the object up via getters and setters.